# Phantomjs and sessions

Tags: session, cookies, authentication, phantomjs

I can't maintain session surfing through a website once logged in.

I do can successfully login on the site (i specify that whatever the page is, after the login you will be redirected to the homepage) but then I have to move to another page. First I tried with page.open() then with page.evaluate changing the location.href window property, but in both cases unfortunately the result is that I'm not logged in anymore. I traced the login status just rendering the page on every page load event with incremental png names (1.png, 2.png, etc) . I also tried with --cookies-file=cookies.txt param but it didn't help much.

My questions are:
What is the best way to "move" through site pages with phantomjs?
Is there a specific way to handle sessions in these cases (maybe sending cookies manually on each .open(), just saying)?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same problem. I have tried the --cookies-file parameter as well, I can see that the login action got executed correctly, but when it redirect to the next page, the user was not logged in. Definitely a session problem. looking forward for the solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem ? Still struggling and can't find anything to avoid compromise data security.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sessions require cookies. You have to add an extra argument in phantomjs.

```
--cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt
```

Look [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference) for more info.

**Edit** :
Does your `cookies.txt` contains something ?

Comment: Yes it does but I still can't keep myself logged in though. I also tried to delete the old cookie.txt file, launching the script again and see if cookie data is being correctly written on it and it seems to.

Comment: @razorxan so your problem seems to be solved? if it is please mark the above question as correct.. so that we don't leave this open ended

Comment: @abbood no, his problem is not solved. Cookie data is being written correctly but he still loses his login session (like me now...)

Answer (score 8):

I had issues with the cookies file approach.  The file would be written, and I could see "cookie information" in the file, but future requests would be interpreted as unauthenticated.  As a last ditch effort, I simply took the page.cookies array, serialized it to JSON and saved it to a file.  My next script would open the file, deserialize it to a variable and set the page.cookies to the variable.  Sure enough this worked!  Just thought I would pass it along.

Comment: This is a known issue apparently: see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12277 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/24184040/308421

Comment: Here is a gist to do this (although the option -cookies-file seems to be working for non-session cookies) : [https://gist.github.com/jarnix/8d6e279d7571da7fe3227f1e103f5562](https://gist.github.com/jarnix/8d6e279d7571da7fe3227f1e103f5562)