# "Listening" to AJAX calls from Capybara / Selenium - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, capybara, teaspoon

I have an app which makes AJAX calls on certain events (e.g. `.click`). Is there a way to "listen" to real AJAX requests from `feature specs`with `Capybara` / `Selenium`?

I tried the [`Teaspoon gem`](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon), but apparently its only allowing accessing fixture URLs ([as per this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968231/visit-pages-using-phantomjs-directly-when-writing-specs-with-teaspoon-jasmine)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't listen to events in the browser from Capybara, you can only look for changes that occur as a result of those events.  ie. If clicking a button makes an ajax request and then changes part of the page, check for the element that is added/removed from the page.