# Format for storing cookies in a txt file and serving it to phantomjs

Tags: cookies, phantomjs

I am trying to send cookies to phantomjs while starting the driver
`phanton.add_cookie({})` works.

I want to keep a list of cookies in a file and pass them as arguments while launching phantomjs

I found that `webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--cookies-file=/tmp/ph_cook.txt'])` would add a given `txt` file at launch.

The problem is I do not know what format this txt file should be of. I tried using a map with key value pair, but no gain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use persisted cookies from a file using phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739354/how-can-i-use-persisted-cookies-from-a-file-using-phantomjs)

Answer (score 0):

The cookie file format is a Qt internal serialization format of cookies. If you need such a cookie file, follow those instructions:

1. Create a PhantomJS script which sets the cookies that you need either using [`phantom.addCookie()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/add-cookie.html) or [`page.addCookie()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/add-cookie.html).
2. Run the previously written script as

   ```
   $ phantomjs --cookies-file=cookies.txt script.js
   ```
3. Use the generated cookies file in python.